# How to perform calculations with useState variables that handle increment and decrement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

What my code wants to achieve is -- when I click the increment button, the increment value `quantityCount` is used to multiply the object `sellingPrice`. But what I get is -- the initial value of the `quantityCount` multiplies the `sellingPrice`, but when I increase the count `quantityCount` it doesn't dynamically multiply the `sellingPrice` object as shown in the console.

Would appreciate your help on this, thanks.

```
  const [productName, setProductName] = useState("");
  const [sellingPrice, setSellingPrice] = useState(0);
  const [quantityCount, setQuantityCount] = useState(0); //useState Variable handling my Increment and Decrement
  const [newItems, setNewItems] = useState([])

  const enterProductName = (e) =>{
      setProductName(e.target.value);
  }
  const enterSellingPrice = (e) =>{
      let sellingPricePerEach = e.target.value
      setSellingPrice(sellingPricePerEach * quantityCount);

      console.log(sellingPricePerEach * quantityCount);
  }
  let handleSaveItem = () => {
      const newItemData = {productName, sellingPrice,quantityCount};
      setNewItems([...newItems, newItemData]);
      console.log(newItemData);
  }
  let incrementQuantity = () =>{
      setQuantityCount(quantityCount+ 1);
      //console.log(quantityCount+ 1);
  }
  let decrementQuantity = () =>{
      setQuantityCount(quantityCount- 1);
     // console.log(quantityCount- 1);

  }

//JSX
<div>Items</div>
{newItems.map((items)=>{
    const {productName,sellingPrice, quantityCount} = items;
    return(
        <>
        <div>
        <div><div>{productName}</div>
            <div>{sellingPrice}</div>
        </div>
        <div><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashCan} /></div>
        
    </div>
    
    </>
    );
})}

//JSX
<div>Quantity</div>
<div>
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} onClick={incrementQuantity}/>
    {quantityCount}
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMinus} onClick={decrementQuantity}/>
</div>
```

Comment: You'd need to react to the value of `quantityCount` changing and update `sellingPrice` probably using a `useEffect`. If this gets any more complicated, or maybe just for cleanliness, you could look at using `useReducer` and fire off actions that can change multiple parts of the state you are tracking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jacob already answered the question, but here is the answer to extend his comment -- use `useEffect`

The reason it doesn't work from your original logic is the state stays the same (in this case, `quantityCount`) until the next render. That is why when you clicked "Increment", the `quantityCount` being used is still the old one rather than the updated one you've been expecting.

In this case, we need a way to "watch" the `quantityCount`, so when we can update the `sellingPrice` as `quantityCount` changes.

This can be achieved by adding the following lines in your component --

```
useEffect(()=>{
  if (quantityCount === 0) return // safeguard invalid value
  setSellingPrice(quantityCount * sellingPrice)
}, [quantityCount])
```

(Unrelated -- `useReducer` is another technique for increment and decrement a state, but it a bit overkill for the simple state management in this component)

Example code https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-butterfly-9vmp2x?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: it worked@Taiwei but for small numbers, if I startup calculating larger numbers the calculation puts out wrong values

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more on "if I startup calculating larger numbers the calculation puts out wrong values"? some examples would be preferable

Comment: Ok, @Taiwei, this is what happens, there is a form where I enter selling price, and a separate button(the fontawsome icons) which I click to increment and decrement count, and another button to submit, after entering the sellingPrice and choosing the quantity count, when click to submit, the actual calculation that happen isnt really quantityCount * sellingPrice, I cant really figure out where the answer it displays comes from, some instances it shows up the correct answer another instance it shows up a wrong answer.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination, but i can't reproduce the weirdness you are talking about. So anyways, here's the Codesandbox i created to demonstrate how it all works with the `useEffect` block I posted. https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-butterfly-9vmp2x?file=/src/App.tsx Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, I figured it out and it worked my problem was I was `setSellingPrice(sellingPricePerEach * quantityCount);` I had  to create another useState Variable that holds the calculation and another that holds the input from the form. The reconstruction you did with codesandbox was helpfull, it worked too, showed another  and better way of achieving the same goal. Thanks. pls can you clearify what this works? `Number(inputRef.current?.value ?? "0");`

Comment: The input type is `text`, so the value coming from it is a string instead of a number, and its just a good practice to convert the value into same `number` type before the calculation, thus the `Number()`. Moreover, the `??` is a similar version of `||`, but `??` only fall back when the value is either `null` or `undefined`, which is just another safer practice for coding in general.

Comment: Thank you so much @Taiwei for the clear explanation.I have learnt alot from just this challenge.